# Form closing itself

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to C# (switching from Java) and i'm having a bit of trouble understanding GUI in C#

Ill just paste the Code i have and let that explain the most part.

Main Class:

```
 Frame frame;
 keepRunning = true;

 public GraphicsComponent()
 {
     frame = new Frame();
     frame.Show();
 }

 public void run()
 {
    while (keepRunning)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Running");
    }
 }

 public static void Main()
 {
    GraphicsComponent gameComponent = new GraphicsComponent();

    gameComponent.run();
}
```

using the frame.Show() method, it appears and disappears for a quick moment. but the "running" loop is run.

The other way i have seen is another method called ShowDialoge(), that one keeps the window open but blocks the rest of the code from running until it is closed.

The way i want to use it is basically how GUIs work in Java. Where i can reference an object (and it's components) as needed in the rest of my code.

Thanks heaps!

Edit: There is alot of confusion, so here is my Frame class:

```
public partial class Frame : Form
{
    public Frame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the winforms designer? Usually you would create a class (Form1 for example) that inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form, and call Application.Run(new Form1()); in your main method.

Comment: Yeah this is an odd setup... Also where is keepRunning defined?

Comment: You should probably be using a Form. A Frame is not what you need and is WPF not WinForms

Comment: @Alan im not suing a Frame, i've just called the class Frame, it's a Form. And Running was meant to be keepRunning.

Answer (score 1):

A normal way to kick off a winforms application is by  file->new winforms project. WHen you do this you get "Program.cs", which contains your Main method - the entry point into your application. From there you have code like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new ConfigForm());
    }
```

In this example I kick off a new "ConfigForm"" that is a Form, and contains in it's ctor some code that looks like this:

```
    public ConfigForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Other init work here

    }
```

I create the form by right-clicking in the project and adding a new form.

You might want to look into the `Application.Run` method, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900.aspx). You can specify a "Main Form" which is going to be the main form that runs for the duration of the application, and when closed ends the application, or you can specify other options if you want. Perhaps the simplest solution is to start a main form, and since the form is live for the duration of the application, you can kick off other long-running code inside that form. If it's code that you want to be executing all the time performing some sort of background operation then you might want to fire it off in it's own thread. However, threading is hard so if you're new to c# / .net I'd try to stay away from threading unless you need it.

Comment: Im using a Form, the call is just called Frame. and how would i be able to run code outside of the Form?